# How do I add a horizontal 1px white line below the button in a relative layout?

Tags: android, xml

How can I add a horizontal 1px white line below the button in a relative layout

Comment: a beloved button? "below" the button?

Comment: clearly state your problem with code !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code will do that.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/devider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
/>
```

Comment: 1dp is not the same thing as 1px

Comment: Yes. You are right. But as per standard guideline, it is better to use dp instead of px. You can also set "1px" instead of "1dp" but you think of how it will be displayed for "xxxhdpi" phone. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set LinearLayout with white background like following.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:background="#FFFFFF" >
</LinearLayout>
```